# passing argument by using CallNonvirtualVoidMethod

Tags: android-ndk, java-native-interface

I have a JNI function calling an instance method within an Android activity. I am using CallNonvirtualVoidMethod. Like this:

```
jarray buffer = (*env)->NewByteArray(env, len);
void* pBuffer = (*env)->GetPrimitiveArrayCritical(env, buffer, NULL);
// ... load data to buffer via pBuffer
(*env)->ReleasePrimitiveArrayCritical(env, buffer, pBuffer, 0);
(*env)->CallNonvirtualVoidMethod(env, o, c, m); // associate m with java method name 'mMethod' somewhere
(*env)->DeleteLocalRef(env, buffer);
```

If no argument passed (like above nothing after 'm'), everything works. But if with argument (even only one single integer like: (*env)->CallNonvirtualVoidMethod(env, o, c, m, msg);), the activity seems not receiving them properly (but I am sure it is called). Like this:

```
public void mMethod(int msg) {
    Log.i("aaa", "I am here"); <----------------successfully printed in logcat
    Log.i("aaa", "I hate: " + msg);<------------not got printed
}
```

I am using ndk-r8-crystax. Anyone can help me out? Thanks.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Problem is gone when I call another class rather than any activity. Guess the reason is an activity cannot be communicated with primitives/references as arguments.